# JSF2 Multiple Button Submission

Tags: jsf-2

In JSF2, is there any way to handle the multiple form submit (user clicks submit button multiple times)? Now we are getting the below exception in server
I tried with setTimeOut(disable button) , but still gets the same error.

WARNING: socket write error: Connection aborted by peer
javax.faces.FacesException: socket write error: Connection aborted by peer
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:126)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:783)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1248)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)